# Is there a more efficient way to write IF statements that use DateTime values?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a hefty list of if statements which compare the current date to a set due date, it then displays how many days remain until the deadline or show if it has already been met. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to go about this.

Below is an example of one of the 'sets' of statements, there are around 7 more of these. It's almost kind of gross, looking for a little help or a point in the right direction in how I can tidy it up. Thanks!

```
if (DateTime.Now >= programming1)
{
    lblReadDate.Text = "Due date for Programming Assignment 1 has been reached (" + programming1.ToShortDateString() + ").";
}
else
{
    lblReadDate.Text = "Days remaining until Programming Assignment 1 deadline: " + daysRemaining1.ToString("0");
}

if (DateTime.Now >= programming2)
{
    lblReadDate2.Text = "Due date for Programming Assignment 2 has been reached (" + programming2.ToShortDateString() + ").";
}
else
{
    lblReadDate2.Text = "Days remaining until Programming Assignment 2 deadline: " + daysRemaining2.ToString("0");
}
```

Comment: Anything that looks like copy/pasted code is gross, indeed. Use lists, like a `List<DateTime>` for the due times and a `List<Label>`, along with a `for` loop to clean this. Can't tell much more with the snippet you posted.

Comment: It looks like your question is more about eliminating duplicated code than about if-statements or the DateTime struct.  Consider extracting a method that takes a few parameters and that would return the desired string value.

Comment: @CalebBell I guess it is more about eliminating duplicated code, my apologies!

Comment: Thanks @LucasTrzesniewski I'll give that a go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell what approach will work best for you, but I am presuming you will generally want to have a class that represents an assignment, e.g.:

```
public class Assignment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    // This is just one of many ways to do it.
    // This can be an extension method, for example.
    // Note also that DateTime.UtcNow is changing as 
    // you are traversing the list.
    public bool IsOverdue
    {
       get { return DateTime.UtcNow > DueDate; }
    }
}
```

General way to associate two entities (in this case, an assignment instance and a label) would be through a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. In this case you might map by assignment name, to keep things simple:

```
// This is just one of many ways to do it.
// You could make Assignment implement IEquatable, or
// specify a custom comparer and map from actual
// Assignment to a Label, for instance.
var assignmentToLabelMap = new Dictionary<string, Label>
{
    { "Programming Assignment 1", label1 },
    { "Programming Assignment 2", label2 },
    { "Programming Assignment 3", label3 }
}
```

Once you have this in place, your UI updates are simple:

```
// Get the assignments
IList<Assignment> assignments = GetTheListOfAssignments();

// Update labels
foreach (var assignment in assignments)
{
    // no error checking here whatsoever
    var label = assignmentToLabelMap[assignment.Name];

    if (assignment.IsOverdue)
        label.Text = xxx;
    else
        label.Text = yyy;
}
```

Since you seem to be using WinForms, you might also want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and configure control binding to make all this happen automagically, but something still needs to iterate through the list at some time to trigger the change.

Comment: Thanks Groo - I appreciate it, I am giving this a go right now.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have repeated code you should look for a way to generalize it and that usually means moving that code into a method or even a new class. Something like this would work for now. I am not using a loop because I saw you are assigning the text to a label depending on the value you are checking.

```
lblReadDate.Text = compareDate(programming1, "Programming Assignment 1");
lblReadDate2.Text = compareDate(programming2, "Programming Assignment 2");

// common method
public string compareDate(DateTime dateToCompare, string name) {
    if (DateTime.Now >= dateToCompare)
        return "Due date for " + name + " has been reached (" + dateToCompare.ToShortDateString() + ").";
    return "Days remaining until " + name + " deadline: " + dateToCompare.ToString("0");
}
```

You should also look at using `string.Format` which could clean up your string concanitations (*it does not do anything for performance in this case, just makes it a bit easier to read*).

Answer (score 1):

What about turning progamming1, progamming2, progamming3,... into a DateTime[]? You can use a for loop and keep a counter and just use counter.ToString() for the assignment number.

Comment: They already are DateTime, but I'll try to look more into this. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Ternary Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to tidy it up visually?

```
lblReadDate.Text = DateTime.Now >= programming1 ?
     string.format("Due date for Programming Assignment 1 has been reached ({0})", programming1.ToShortDateString()) :
     string.format(""Days remaining until Programming Assignment 1 deadline: {0}", daysRemaining1.ToString("0"));
```

That said, an extension method would help further:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CompareDateToNow(this DateTime compareFrom)
    {
        return DateTime.Now >= compareTo;
    }
}
```

Then it becomes:

```
lblReadDate.Text = programming1.CompareDateToNow() ?
     string.format("Due date for Programming Assignment 1 has been reached ({0})", programming1.ToShortDateString()) :
     string.format(""Days remaining until Programming Assignment 1 deadline: {0}", daysRemaining1.ToString("0"));
```

You could further rationalise the strings in the statements, and ultimately just pass the dates and programme name into it's own method.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to refactor this kind of code.

you can put the code in an extension method and just call it.

for example

```
lblReadDate.Text = programming1.GetAssignmentMessage("1", daysRemaining1);
lblReadDate2.Text = programming2.GetAssignmentMessage("2", daysRemaining2);
```

Extension Method:

```
public static string GetAssignmentMessage(this DateTime programming, string assignment, int daysRemaining)
{
if (DateTime.Now >= programming)
{
    return "Due date for Programming Assignment " + assignment + " has been reached (" + programming.ToShortDateString() + ").";
}
else
{
    return "Days remaining until Programming Assignment " + assignment + " deadline: " + daysRemaining.ToString("0");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have class like below for you program.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }  
    }
```

The you can pass your program object to method like follow to get required message.

```
    Public string GetMessage(Program program)
    {

      if(DateTime.Now > Program.DueDate)
        return string.Format("Due date for Programming Assignment {0} has been reached {1}.",Program.Name,Program.DueDate);    
      else
        string.Format("Days remaining until Programming Assignment {0} deadline: {1}",Program.Name,Program.DueDate);

    }
```

If you need to check this in collection of program objects. Modify GetMessage method as required.

I hope this will help you. Happy coding. :)